# Is there a subject vs. object distinction like who/whom?

Tags: preguntas

In English “who” is used as a subject:

> Who is eating?

“Whom” is used as an object:

> The person whom I saw.

**In Spanish is there any sort of a distinction like this, or is “quien” both for subjects and objects?**

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.  Interrogative words in Spanish don't retain any renmants of case distinction (unless you count *cúyo*, which I suppose we could call the genetive of *quién*).

In your two sentences, you'd get *¿**Quién** está comiendo?* and *La persona a **quien** vi*.

Note, however, that Spanish *greatly* prefers using *que* in relative clauses, so while *la persona a quien vi* is fine, you will rarely hear it in most dialects, with *la persona que vi* being the preferred construction.

Comment: Is it a typo that there's an accent in the first "quien" but not the second?

Comment: @Stormblessed no.  In the first one, *quién* is used as a question word with takes an accent because it is stressed.  In the second, it is used as a relative pronoun; they don't take accents because they are unstressed.

Comment: @guifa Shouldn't that be *la persona **a quien** vi comiendo*, with "personal *a*"? It sounds very strange to me without it.

Comment: @pablodf76 ack, yes.  I had originaly written *que* (which is what made me write the latter sentence) but I accidentally only replaced the *quien*.  Fixed.

Comment: Another idiomatic way of using the equivalent of "whom" in Spanish consists of saying *la persona **a la que** vi comiendo*

Comment: genitive, not genetive

Answer (score 0):

My intuitive way of thinking about this is yes, because the *who* compartment in my brain has *quien* in it, and the *whom* compartment has *a quien* in it.  And I think that when an English speaker learns Spanish and gets the hang of saying *a quien* when it is needed, that person has an easier time knowing when one could use *whom* in English, and more importantly, when not to use *whom*.  (For those who aren't aware -- most native English speakers never use *whom* at all.  I used to think it was ignorance only that led to people not using *whom*.  But at ELU, there's a strong anti-*whom* camp, which includes some of the top, most knowledgeable participants.)

Examples:

> ¿Quién está llamando a estas horas?
>
> ¿A quién le importa lo que yo diga?

Comment: Well I personally didn’t ever use it until recently, but because I didn’t understand when or care to.